# Java time expression evaluation

Tags: java, datetime

So I need to have a user input "time expression".

For example:

- user inputs 1w => that's1 week => to seconds
- user inputs 1h => that's1 hour => to seconds
- user inputs 2h10m => that's 2 hours and 10 minits => to seconds
- user inputs 2h 10m => thats 2 hours and 10 minits => to seconds

So my question is:

Do you know any java API/library which can handle this? I need to parse value like:

1y 1m 1w 2h 10m 15s.

Or I will need to write my own parser for this?

EDIT: main goal is to parse user input as String to something better. So im looking for parser... not java code how to convert date to seconds or something

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I do know about joda time, but i'm searcing in their User guide and webpage for some example, even hint, currently no luck

Comment: When you decide to build your own parser, have a look at Regular Expressions. It'll help you parse the given string faster.
(?:(\d)w)? *(?:(\d)h)? *(?:(\d)m)?

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens yes for sure i will use RegEx if i will make my own parser for this, but usually when i have some problem, i look on Internet to see if someone already had same problem... Saving time :)  EDIT: thanks for helping me with RegExp but user should be able to input also: 1y 1m 1w 2h 10m 15s :)

Comment: No need for regex or parsers. Joda-Time has this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Do Not Roll Your Own

No, you definitely do not need to write a parser. Such a parser has already been built and tested, available at no cost: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and its [Period class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

## ISO 8601

An international standard exists, [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), defining a textual format similar to what you are using. The standard calls the [format Durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` stands for Period (yes terms vary and conflict in date-time work). The `T` is a separator between the date portion and the time portion.

## Joda-Time

The Joda-Time class Period both parses and generates this format by default.

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

Construct by using built-in default parser to parse string in ISO 8601 format.

```
String input = "P1Y1M1WT2H10M15S";
Period period = new Period( input );
```

Create a string using the built-in default formatter using the ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = period.toString();
```

Use an alternate constructor, passing the integer number of each field.

```
Period period2 = new Period( 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 10, 15, 0 ); // Period( int years, int months, int weeks, int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis )
```

Use the Period in date-time math. Construct a date-time (first of the year), and then add the Period to arrive at another date-time. Note the use of a specific time zone rather than rely on the JVM's default time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2014, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ));
DateTime dateTimeLater = dateTime.plus( period );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "period2: " + period2 );
System.out.println( "Seconds portion: " + period.getSeconds() );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLater: " + dateTimeLater );
```

When run…

```
input: P1Y1M1WT2H10M15S
output: P1Y1M1WT2H10M15S
period2: P1Y1M1WT2H10M15S
Seconds portion: 15
dateTime: 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
dateTimeLater: 2015-02-08T02:10:15.000+01:00
```

By the way, Joda-Time offers three classes to represent a span of time in different ways: [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), and [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html).

### Caveat – Weeks

My example above uses weeks (`1W`). On further reading it appears that weeks is not an official level of granularity in ISO 8601. Weeks are only meant to be used solo (`PnW`), not combined with other elements. While my code seems to be working in Joda-Time, it may not be strictly compliant with ISO 8601. I cannot investigate further as ISO standards are closed, available only with expensive purchase.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you answer. This looks like right answer. Will try it and confirm later. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library for Java.

Comment: I know about joda. Joda is great and im using joda daily ( Not sure but as i heard, some joda parts are in Java 8 ? :notsure: never mind). But can joda parse user string and give me some Date object ? Can you give me some hint / example ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Formatters would be helpful for you [Joda Time Formatters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Formatters)

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24195243/642706) for full example of using Joda-Time.